# Reasons why Rally Lookback Api isn't working?

Tags: http-status-code-404, rally, lookbackapi

Could someone help me figure out why I can't access the Rally Lookback Api? I can access the webservice just fine.

For example, when I type this into the browser:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/12345/artifact/3563764.js

(using my server name, the correct workspace and a valid ObjectID), I get the HTTP 404 not found error. Is there a specific reason for this? I've tried several different types of queries, and nothing works.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Julie, when you say "my server name", do you mean you have Rally installed in your data center as an on-premise or "behind the firewall" installation (as opposed to the SaaS, Rally hosted application at rally1.rallydev.com)?

Comment: Well, we do have Rally installed in our data center, but I'm still confused about whether it automatically captures Lookback data, or whether we have to configure it, or whether only Rally stores it on their database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookback API works a bit different from WSAPI - there aren't artifact-ObjectID specific endpoints such as the above. Instead, you would want to do a find query:

GET:

`https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/12345678910/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"ObjectID":12345678920}&fields=["_ValidFrom","_ValidTo","ObjectID","State"]&start=0&pagesize=1`

Alternatively, using a POST:

POST against:

URI: `https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/12345678910/artifact/snapshot/query.js`

POST data:

```
{
    "find": { "ObjectID": 12345678920},
    "fields": ["_ValidFrom", "_ValidTo", "ObjectID", "State"],
    "start": 0,
    "pagesize": 1
}
```

There are some good examples of this, along with a query "scratchpad" that you can use to test queries in your browser, in the LookbackAPI docs here:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual

A Rally login is required to use query samples.

Comment: So if I'm thinking about this right, I think my issue is that I don't have access to rally1.rallydev.com. I had assumed that I had access to it just by being a user, but I guess I need a Rally login for that. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks for the GET and POST examples, I hadn't clearly understood how to do a find query either.

Comment: If you have a Rally login, you should be able to enter your standard Rally credentials in the login prompt that the docs pages presents. You can also just cancel through it, the only restriction will be that you won't be able to run the example queries from within the help.

Comment: I think I don't have the right level of permission, because it won't let me through.

Comment: Does your subscription use SSO? I'm not sure if this page supports anything but basic auth - I'll check.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an endpoint for the LBAPI that is similar to the WSAPI artifact endpoint.  It looks like:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/12345/artifact/67890/snapshot/query.js

(Note the oid between /artifact/ and /snapshot/.)  You still have to use a find clause though, to filter which snapshots from that specific artifact you want.

Answer (score 0):

Both MarkW and Joel give some great responses and pointers to where you can get more information about the Lookback API.  However, the real answer to your question is that the Lookback API is currently only available to SaaS customers.  So, since you have Rally inside your datacenter, you won't be able to use the Lookback API until the ability to deploy Lookback to on premise customers is released.